# Powershell unregister-ScheduledTask

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove schedule task on remote servers.

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName "name" {Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task -WhatIf}
```

I get the following error

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TaskName'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Unregister-ScheduledTask], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Unregister-ScheduledTask
>       + PSComputerName        : name

$Task='task'

If I specify the "Taskname" in text and not variable it works.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "name" {Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "task" -WhatIf}
```

> What if: Performing operation 'Delete' on Target '\task'.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a named variable to a scriptblock, do:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {param($task) Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task } -ArgumentList $TaskName
```

or use the `$args` [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args) like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $args[0] } -ArgumentList $TaskName
```

Comment: What if I want to pass multiple -Arguments; ie: -TaskName -confim

Comment: @EricRochon Simply add more `param`s to the scriptblock or use the next `$args` items aswell. `-ArgumentList` can be an array, so comma separate the other values you want to pass

Answer (score -1):

Create the unregister file like this one I use to clear unwanted scheduled tasks:

```
#TaskSchdOptimizer.ps1
get-scheduledtask | where {$_.taskname -like "Optimize Start Menu Cache Files*"} | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
get-scheduledtask | where {$_.taskname -like "GoogleUpdateTaskMachine*"} | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
get-scheduledtask | where {$_.taskname -like "User_Feed*"} | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
```

and then copy the file to the servers, like I do my $profile:

```
#Copy-UnregisterFile.ps1
$serverListFile = gc .\yourinputfolder\serverlist.txt
$file_dir="driveletter$\whereyourfileis" #DO NOT put an ending "\"!!!
#$file_name="yourunregisterfile.ps1" #<-- put yours here and remove #
$from="$file_dir\$file_name"
$dest="driveletter$\folderwhereyouwanttorunitfrom" #DO NOT put an ending "\"!!!
    Foreach ($Server in $ServerListFile){
                 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 #<-- needed now since 2016
                 if ((test-path "\\$Server\driveletter$\folderwhereyouwanttorunitfrom") -ne $true){New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType directory -Path "\\$server\driveletter$\folderwhereyouwanttorunitfrom" -Force -verbose}
                 Copy-Item -Path $from -Destination \\$Server\$dest\ -Force -Verbose
        Write-Host " $server : copied $file_name to $dest"
}
```

...after that run your invoke using the file you sent...